# SQL error [22008]: ERROR: time / date value out of range: "2021-28-05"

Tags: sql

```
 SELECT * FROM envio_remesa e 
 WHERE e.fecha_procesado >= TO_DATE('2021-28-05','YYYY-mm-DD')
 AND e.fecha_procesado < TO_DATE('2021-28-05','YYYY-mm-DD') + 1
```

I do this query and it tells me that it is out of range, why? I have records with that date **2021-28-05**

Comment: There is no month 28. Do you mean May 28th? Would be `2021-05-28`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (TO_DATE is a product specific function.)

Comment: @jarlh im using plain SQL , but can also use postgresql

Comment: Plain SQL, i.e. ANSI/ISO SQL, has no TO_DATE.

Comment: well i solver with 2021-05-28 , i dont know what a fail.. You can answer so i mark as correct your answer

Comment: your format is wrong use "YYYY-mm-dd" and value you have given is wrong it should be "2021-05-28"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct May 28th date is `2021-05-28`, when `YYYY-MM-DD` format.